# kendo ui grid angular 5 mat-menu not closing in kendoGridCellTemplate

Tags: angular, angular-material, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a **mat-menu** inside **kendoGridCellTemplate**, where menu items are created by **ngFor**.

This menu is showing correctly but once we click it's *not getting closed*.

If I use chrome inspector to navigate to that element,it's not there in DOM.

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngIf="shouldCreate" title="Menu">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <mat-menu #actionMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
      <div class="action-menu">
        <a *ngFor="let actionitem of Items;let mi=index"
          [ngClass]="{'border-top':actionitem.HasSeperator}" 
          ng-click='ActionItemClicked(actionitem.MenuTitle,dataItem)'>
          <mat-icon>{{actionitem.MenuIcon}}</mat-icon> 
           {{actionitem.MenuTitle}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="actionMenu">
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Any idea what went wrong here .

Even the simple implementation is not working i.e. menu not getting closed , here is the code:

```
<kendo-grid-column title="Menu Test">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Menu code is copied from [Angular Material Page](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what was the problem. for auto sizing column width I was using a function `grid.autoFitColumn()` that causing this issue, once remove the issue resolve.
But I still need to look what inside that autoFitColumn that causing this issue.